# SQL error: invalid number: not a valid number string

Tags: hana

have the following logic in my calculation view which is throwing an error.

```
 var_out = select  'PO' || cast('_' as varchar) || WERKS ||
                    cast('_' as varchar) || matnr + 
                    cast('_' as varchar) || ebeln as 
                    "EBELN",
                    menge as "Quantity"
                    from "ECC".EKPO;
```

The data type for EBELN field is VARCHAR 100. Can you help me to identify the data type error here?

Comment: You used MATNR + ....   Why did not you use " || " just as cooncatenating others. Please replace "+" with "||" then try once more...

Comment: @gvs - This is duplicate of your previous question. Btw. you don't need to cast data type for underscore, simply add '_'

Comment: @Konza, I will make not to raise duplicate questions. I removed cast for underscore and replaced '+' with || as suggested by Eralper.  My query is working fine now.